# Differentiating with respect to unit vectors on a hypersphere

Tags: calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

I have this 'potential energy' function $V$ defined on $(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{nd}$.

$$V(\{ \hat{\underline s_i} \}) = -\frac{K}{2} \sum_{i,j \ i \neq j}^n J_{ij} \hat{\underline{s}_i} \cdot \hat{\underline{s}_j} - K_s \sum_{i}^n \big(\hat{\underline s_i} \cdot \hat{\underline{z}} \big)^2$$

where

$$ \hat{\underline s_i} \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$$

It determines the dynamics of $n$ unit spins of dimension $d$ via the following partial derivative:

$$\dot{\hat{\underline s_i}} := -\frac{\partial V}{\partial \hat{\underline{s}_i}}$$

In the $d=2$ case, the phase parameterisation of these spins makes taking the partial derivative trivial, but for $d>2$ the parameterisation gets messy so I assumed I'd have an easier time with a geometric description. I'm now struggling to incorporate the $|\underline{s}_i| = 1$ constraints easily into the partial derivatives.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want I think is the covariant derivative on the sphere, but because $V$ is a scalar this is the same as the *tangential derivative* which makes this easy.

If $P_x(v)$ is the projection of a vector $v$ onto the tangent space of the sphere at some point $x$, then the tangential derivative is simply $\partial_x = P_x(\nabla_x)$. Here, $x$ simply denotes the vector variable we're differentiating with respect to, but crucially $\nabla_x$ **is not** differentiating any $x$-dependence of $P$. In terms of the normal vector $n(x)$ this looks like
$$
  \partial_x = \nabla_x - n(x)(n(x)\cdot\nabla_x).
$$

The full derivative $\nabla$ has some basic properties, one of which is
$$
  \nabla_x(x\cdot v) = v
$$
for any $x$-independent vector $v$. But $\partial$ *also* enjoys this property with a twist:
$$
  \partial_x(x\cdot v) = P_x(\nabla_x)(x\cdot v) = P_x(\nabla_x(x\cdot v)) = P_x(v).
$$

Now we can proceed using the product rule and assuming the $\hat s_i$ are mutually independent:
$$\begin{aligned}
  \dot{\hat s}_k &= -\partial_{\hat s_k}V = \frac K2\sum_{i\ne k}(J_{ik}+J_{ki})P_{\hat s_k}(\hat s_i) + 2K_s(\hat s_k\cdot\hat z)P_{\hat s_k}(\hat z)
\\
&= \frac K2\sum_{i\ne k}(J_{ik}+J_{ki})[\hat s_i - (\hat s_i\cdot\hat s_k)\hat s_k] + 2K_s(\hat s_k\cdot\hat z)[\hat z - (\hat z\cdot\hat s_k)\hat s_k].
\end{aligned}$$

---

Suppose now want to compute the "Jacobian" $\partial\dot{\hat s}_i/\partial\hat s_j$. The standard Jacobian $J_F$ of a vector function $F$ in flat space is the matrix representing the *total differential* $\mathrm dF(x; v) = J_Fv$. However, the total differential evaluated on $v$ is (essentially by definition) the $v$-directional derivative of $F$; in terms of $\nabla$ this directional derivative operator is $v\cdot\nabla$, so we have the very convenient form
$$
  \mathrm dF(x; v) = (v\cdot\nabla)F(x).
$$
Once we compute this, we can recover the matrix $J_F$ be evaluating on the standard basis $e_i$:
$$
  (J_F)_{ij} = e_i\cdot[\mathrm dF(x; e_j)].
$$

So the quantities we want to compute are $(v\cdot\partial_{\hat s_i})\dot{\hat s}_j$ for arbitrary $v$. The key identity here is
$$
  (v\cdot\nabla_x)L(x) = L(v),\quad (v\cdot\partial_x)L(x) = L(P_x(v))
$$
where $L$ can be any linear function (this following from the fact that a linear function is its own differential). For brevity write $v' = P_x(v)$. By also using the product rule, we now see
$$
  (v\cdot\partial_{\hat s_k})\dot{\hat s}_k
    = -\frac K2\sum_{i\ne k}(J_{ik}+J_{ki})[(\hat s_i\cdot v')\hat s_k + (\hat s_i\cdot\hat s_k)v'] + 2K_s(v'\cdot\hat z)(\hat z - (\hat z\cdot\hat s_k)\hat s_k) - 2K_s(\hat s_k\cdot\hat z)(\hat z\cdot v')\hat s_k - 2K_s(\hat s_k\cdot\hat z)^2v'
$$
and when $j \ne k$
$$
  (v\cdot\partial_{\hat s_j})\dot{\hat s}_k
    = \frac K2(J_{jk} + J_{kj})[v' - (v'\cdot\hat s_k)\hat s_k].
$$
To get the matrix components, we can do is write dot products with $v$ in the matrix form $w^Tv$ and try to get the overall form $Jv$ with $J$ a matrix. First note that
$$
  v' = v - (v\cdot\hat s_j)\hat s_j = (1 - \hat s_j\hat s_j^T)v.
$$
So when $j = k$
$$
  -\frac K2\sum_{i\ne k}(J_{ik} + J_{ki})[\hat s_k\hat s_i^T + \hat s_i\cdot\hat s_k]v' + 2K_s\Bigl[(1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T)\hat z\hat z^T - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T\hat zz^T - (\hat s_k\cdot\hat z)^2\Bigr]v'
$$
and when $j \ne k$
$$
  \frac K2(J_{jk} + J_{kj})[1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T]v'.
$$
Finally, we get the matrix expressions
$$
  \frac{\partial\dot{\hat s}_k}{\partial\hat s_k}
    = M[1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T],\quad
  \frac{\partial\dot{\hat s}_k}{\partial\hat s_j}
    = \frac K2(J_{jk} + J_{kj})[1-\hat s_k\hat s_k^T][1-\hat s_j\hat s_j^T],
$$$$
  M = -\frac K2(\hat s_kS_k^T + \hat s_k\cdot S_k) + 2K_s\Bigl[(1-2\hat s_k\hat s_k^T)\hat z\hat z^T - (\hat s_k\cdot\hat z)^2\Bigr],
$$$$
  S_k = \sum_{i\ne k}(J_{ik} + J_{ki})\hat s_i.
$$
The terms $\hat s_k\cdot S_k$ and $(\hat s_k\cdot\hat z)^2$ should be interpreted as multiplying an identity matrix.

**Edit:** It occurred to me that maybe we want the covariant directional derivatives here rather than the tangential; we were in fact using the tangential derivative as a special case of the covariant derivative. This is easy though; following Doran and Lasenby (as I mention in the comments), the covariant directional derivative is just the projection of the tangential one. This means all we need to do is multiply the above Jacobians on the left by $[1 - \hat s_j\hat s_j^T]$.

Therefore the final results would be:

$$
  \frac{\partial\dot{\hat s}_k}{\partial\hat s_k}
    = [1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T]M[1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T] $$

$$\frac{\partial\dot{\hat s}_k}{\partial\hat s_j}
    = [1 - \hat s_j\hat s_j^T]\frac K2(J_{jk} + J_{kj})[1-\hat s_k\hat s_k^T][1-\hat s_j\hat s_j^T]$$

Comment: Many thanks for this reply, I must say I'm surprised but pleased that it has such a tractable solution. Unfortunately, from my physics background, I have insufficient knowledge of covariant and tangential derivatives in this context to fully understand your answer - are there any well known references you recommend?

Comment: Also would I be correct in thinking that, before I brush up on my understanding, if I wanted to find another quantity given by $\frac{\partial \hat s_k}{\partial\hat s_j}$ I would just have to use the same $\partial_x = \nabla_x - n(x)(n(x) \cdot \nabla_x)$ trick with $x=\hat s_j$ and where $\nabla_x$ is the 'naive' total derivative where we neglect the fact that each spin's components are coupled such that they maintain unit norm $|\hat s_x| = 1$?

Comment: @AlexGower I was pulling from section 6.1 & 6.5 of *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby which is about [geometric algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra)/[calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_calculus), but in this case the ideas are understandable/applicable using standard vector calculus. There are probably other references about tangential derivatives from a vector calculus perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, and to clarify my second comment, the main quantity I'm looking to calculate is the Jacobian defined as the partial derivative of the dynamics with respect to a spin i.e. $M_{ij} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{s_j}} \Big( \dot{\hat s_i} \Big)$. I think the 'dot' may have been missed in my initial comment.

Comment: @AlexGower Ah, I see. I can do that, I will edit. It proceeds in the same way as before, the trick is that $\mathrm dF_x(v) = (v\cdot\nabla_x)F(x)$ for any $F$, so in this case the quantity we want to compute is $(v\cdot\partial_{s_i})\dot{\hat s}_j$.

Comment: Would it be possible for you be able to add this quantity to the original answer?

Comment: @AlexGower Done!

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to elaborate a bit more about what you were saying in your edit? I'm still a bit unclear about the difference between the 'covariant directional derivatives' and the 'tangential derivative', and why the tangential derivative isn't sufficient in this case?

Comment: My use-case here for the Jacobian is that I want to calculate the change in the time evolution of $\hat s_i$, i.e. $\partial \dot{\hat s_i}$, as I perform an infinitesimal change $\partial \hat s_j$ at some point $x$ (in a manifold) which describes a configuration of unit norm spins. Obviously $\partial \hat s_j$ should be in a direction which keeps us on the manifold (i.e. keeps all spins unit norm) - I think this is what your $(v \cdot \partial_x)$ ensures (am I right?).

Comment: However I don't think we need this quantity to then be projected again onto the tangent space of the manifold (is this what your final edit suggests?). Although my intuition isn't strong so I could be easily convinced that this is in fact the more relevant quantity. What do you think?

Comment: Actually I think you're right, eventhough I think the tangential derivative produces the most 'literal' result of how the time evolution of $\hat s_i$ changes as you change $\hat s_j$. For my situation of using the Jacobian to analyse stability of a dynamical flow defined on the manifold, it makes more sense to use the covariant directional derivative I think

Comment: @AlexGower I think you get it. The tangential derivative just tells us how a quantity changes as you move along the manifold, but because the manifold is embedded in a higher dimensional space some of the change might take you off the manifold. The covariant derivative is the part of the tangential derivative that is intrinsic to the manifold, i.e. the projection onto the tangent spaces. For a scalar field tangential = covariant because because a scalar field only changes tangentially, but for a vector field this need not be the case.

Comment: Whatever you do with your derivatives, I believe you're going to want to project back onto the manifold anyway, so the covariant derivative is the right choice.

Comment: To be absolutely sure, the covariant derivative would produce the following results right?

$\boxed{\frac{\partial\dot{\hat s}_k}{\partial\hat s_k}
    = [1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T]M[1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T]}$, $\boxed{\frac{\partial\dot{\hat s}_k}{\partial\hat s_j}
    = [1 - \hat s_j\hat s_j^T]
    KJ_{kj}[1-\hat s_k\hat s_k^T][1-\hat s_j\hat s_j^T]}$ (with $M$ defined as before)

Comment: @AlexGower Yes, that's it.

Comment: Okay I've read through much of Doran and Lasenby and I think I understand everything a bit better. My one final confusion is, how did you derive the form of the projection $\partial_x = \nabla_x - n(x)(n(x)\cdot\nabla_x)$? I mean it is intuitively obvious but is there a mechanistic way of deriving it? For instance Doran and Lasenby have the form $P(A_r(x),x) = A_r(x) \cdot I(x) I^{-1}(x)$? Similarly, is there a rigorous way of showing that we can use $\hat s_k(x)$ for $n(x)$ in your formula - again it makes sense in my mental picture but is there a sharper argument? Thanks

Comment: Also now I'm thinking $\partial_x = \nabla_x - n(x)(n(x)\cdot\nabla_x)$ is only valid when we are considering a change in only a single spin $\hat s_i$ (rather than a simultaneous change of several spins). Luckily this is all I need for my problem, but is my thinking about this correct?

Comment: @AlexGower Projection onto a subspace ($I$) is the same as *rejection* from its orthogonal complement ($n$). You could could prove this by writing $I(x) = Jn(x)$ with $J$ the ambient pseudoscalar and then doing some manipulations. We can take $n = \hat s_k$ when computing $\partial_{\hat s_k}$ because we're considering $\hat s_k$ as a point on a manifold we're differentiating over; that manifold is a sphere at the origin, so the normal vector a point is the same as the position vector of that point: $\hat s_k$. Essentially we're saying $n(\hat s_k) = \hat s_k$.

Comment: @AlexGower If the $\hat s_k$ are dependent on each other, that is a much more difficult situation to reason about. But I think the formula still holds (at least I can't see why it wouldn't); what happens instead is that you now have nontrivial differentials $(v\cdot\nabla_{\hat s_k})\hat s_j$ and have to compute accordingly.

Comment: Okay thanks, so the real key to being able to do this simple calculation at all is the fact that the n spins are independent of each other in the constraints that define the full (non spherical shell) manifold over n-spin-d configurations. That's what allows us to write such a simple projection operator

Comment: and I guess one final check is that I was incorrect in my comment above, I think it should be $\boxed{\frac{\partial\dot{\hat s}_k}{\partial\hat s_j}
    = [1 - \hat s_k\hat s_k^T]
    KJ_{kj}[1-\hat s_k\hat s_k^T][1-\hat s_j\hat s_j^T]}$ since I think we're working in the tangent space of $\hat s_k$ not $\hat s_j$?

Comment: @AlexGower No, the $\hat s_j$-on-the-left version is correct, we're taking the covariant derivative with respect to $\hat s_j$ so that is the appropriate projection. In Doran and Lasenby you would replace $x$ everywhere by $\hat s_j$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148167/discussion-between-alex-gower-and-nicholas-todoroff).